# Как в tkinter при вводе числа в поле Entry вывести новое окно с количеством полей Entry, равным введенному числу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Встала задачка - пишу программу, в которой необходимо ввести в поле `entry` количество точек многоугольника, а затем вывести новое окно с количеством полей `entry`, равным введённому числу (для ввода координат каждой точки).

Так и не докопался сам, как это реализовать.

```
from tkinter import *

def point_amount():
    global p_points
    p_points = int(p_entry.get())


root = Tk()
root.title("Многоугольник")

p_label = Label(text="Кол-во точек многоугольника:")

p_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

p_entry = Entry()

p_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

display_button = Button(text="OK", command=point_amount)
display_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `exec` .........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *

def point_amount():
    global p_points
    p_points = int(p_entry.get())
    
    top = Toplevel(root)
    list_entry = []
    
    for i in range(p_points):
        _entry = Entry(top)  # top
        list_entry.append(_entry)
        list_entry[-1].grid(row = i, column = 1)
        
    def click():    
        for i in list_entry:
            print(i.get())        
        
    btn = Button(top, text = 'Go ...', comman = click) 
    btn.grid(row = i+1, column = 1)


root = Tk()
root.title("Многоугольник")

p_label = Label(text="Кол-во точек многоугольника:")

p_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

p_entry = Entry()

p_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

display_button = Button(text="OK", command=point_amount)
display_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

def point_amount():
    p_points = int(p_entry.get())#не советовал бы использовать глобальную переменную. Если так нужно - создайте класс
    new_window = Toplevel(root)#
    entries = []#тут будут храниться поля
    for i in range(p_points):
        #для каждой точки создаем Entry
        row = i*2+2#можно просто i+1, но так между ними будет расстояние
        row_title = i*2+1

        title = Label(new_window,text="Поле %i"%(i+1))
        title.grid(row=row_title, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        entry=Entry(new_window)
        entry.grid(row=row, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        entries.append(entry)
        
        
root = Tk()
root.title("Многоугольник")

p_label = Label(text="Кол-во точек многоугольника:")

p_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

p_entry = Entry()

p_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

display_button = Button(text="OK", command=point_amount)
display_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```